# reverse a word + a big bonus ( bug )

Tags: c, arrays, reverse, sizeof

I have just started in C language and I wrote this code to reverse  words, But I have found a small thing and I don't know if it is a bug or a language future.

The purpose of the code is this:

> Simple Input: Welcome
>
> Simple Output: emoclew

The code is working fine, but when We define the variable `patrol` before the variable `size` the program doesn't work. Also if you define the variable `counter` after the variable `size` and the variable `patrol` is before variable `size` the program will work just fine.

The question is: Why does this happen?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char name[ 100 ];
  int counter;
  int size;
  int patrol = 0;

  for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++, patrol++)
      {
        name[ counter ] = getchar();
        size = sizeof(name);

        if (10 == name[ counter ])
            {
              break;
            }
      }

        for(counter = patrol; counter >= 0; counter--)
            {
              printf("%c", name[ counter ]);
            }
              printf("\n");

  return 0;
}// end of main
```

Comment: `size` is uninitialised before you start iterating to it. Your program has undefined behaviour and makes no sense as written. Initialise to the correct size before starting the loop. Think about the code and this will be very clear.

Comment: What do you think this line does? `size = sizeof(name);` Make size the length of the input? Make size the highest valid index of `name[]`? Make size 100? When do you expect the value of size to change? At input? With each new character?

Comment: your problem will be fixed and code behaviour will be as expected once you initialise the `size` variable. C variables are references to memory and if you do not assign any value it can point to some garbage value. this garbage value can sometime be interpreted as int type as well. your program have unexpected behaviour because you have not assigned any value to the variable `size`. now it might be working if you initialise patrol first because then some garbage value is being referenced by the next variable created and in your case its `size` variable.

Comment: @Adam I agree that people should turn on, and then read, basically all available warnings. However, I'm not sure how being on Linux or using Vim would help them do that, if they didn't already know they should. (Btw, I code un Linux using Vim, fwiw.)

Comment: when coding on linux and with simple code editor like gedit or geany or vim that doesnot highlite code bugs and so on, and compile with all consirvitive gcc flags, thats make you a better c programmer!

Comment: Even with a super editor, you should always compile with ***warnings enabled*** `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS (if using another compiler - check documentation for options) Do not accept code until it compiles without warning.

Comment: @Saifee I tried to do that, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @underscore_d  I tried to do that, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @RubberBee this is a lot of questions.

Comment: and you should be asking yourself those questions and more while writing code, instead of just guessing...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I agree

Comment: @Adam yea that's the best, but for someone just started like me, It is better to use warnings.

Comment: @underscore_d I am not guessing.... I am asking questions ..... this is why I am here

Answer (score 2):

This loop

```
for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++, patrol++)
```

invokes undefined behavior because the variable `size` is not initialized before the loop

```
int size;
```

This statement

```
size = sizeof(name);
```

does not make great sense because the expression `sizeof(name)` always yields `100` that is the size of the declared array `name`

```
char name[ 100 ];
```

In this if statement

```
if (10 == name[ counter ])
```

it is better to use the character `'\n'` instead of the magic number `10`.

Also this statement

```
name[ counter ] = getchar();
```

stores the new line character in the array `name`.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char name[ N ];

    int c;
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < N && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' )
    {
        name[i++] = c;
    }

    while ( i != 0 )
    {
        putchar( name[--i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
Hello Eryano
```

then the program output will be

```
onayrE olleH
```

Comment: thank you for your help, your code is great, but even when I initialize ( size ) it doesn't make any difference. the code works fine when I define patrol after size.. if you have an idea please tell me .... and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you mean when you _declare_ those, or when you _assign/define_ them? If the order of declarations alone makes a difference in this case, then you have undefined behaviour. Compilers with decent warnings might well point out where that mistake(s) are arising.

Comment: @underscore_d yes, that's what I meant .. The order of the definition makes a difference and that's weird. And I wanna know the reason behind that.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest the below code. Consider having a look at it :-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()  {
    int counter,size=0;
    char name[100];

    printf("\nEnter a text : ");
    while(1)    {                        // Iterates until 'Enter' is pressed.
        name[size++] = getchar();
        if(name[size-1]=='\n')  break;
    }
    name[--size]='\0';                   // Null character added to complete string...

    printf("\nReverse text : ");
    for(counter=size-1;counter>=0;counter--)    {
        printf("%c",name[counter]);
    }
}
```